# Good introductory book in geometric probability

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, education, geometric-probability

I recently came across the proof of the Buffon theorem and I was fascinated by geometric probability.

Could someone indicate me a good introductory book? Maybe with many exercises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This book will do:
Stochastic Geometry and Its Applications, 3rd Edition
Sung Nok Chiu, Dietrich Stoyan, Wilfrid S. Kendall, Joseph Mecke